# Inflate a layout into Text View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I want to inflate a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` and `ImageView`, into a `TextView` or `AutoCompeleteTextView`.

Something like this:

[image]

I try with these, but it doesn't work:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.test3, null);

TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvInAuto);
textView.setText(number);

ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tvReceiver);

insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

in this code:

`tvReceiver` is my `AutoCompeleteTextView`.

Comment: You can't inflate anything in a "non ViewGroup". Anyway, lucky you, there's **no need** to do that: you can insert a **compound drawable** (an image or a drawable) into a TextView, **directly** (which is also a less-known best practice).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thank you for your quick reply. but i still have problem when i want put more than one string into the textview like the image above. can you make a sample. thanks

Comment: Those aren't "strings" being added to the textview, they are compound drawables as Frank stated. Are you trying to make your own autocomplete textview? If not, where did you get the image demonstrating this?

Comment: Sidenote: you may want to check out this library. https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/

Comment: thank you @cricket_007. I got it now.sorry.